# How to have a storyboard use a border in a calendar control template

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml

I have edited the CalendarItem Template of the Calendar control.  I have added my own border to this template.

I am implementing the Calendar with my CalendarItemStyle.

I normally have a StoryBoard like this

```
<Storyboard x:Key="sbBorderHighlighted">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="1"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

and i call it like this

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter">
    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="sbBorderHighlighted_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource sbBorderHighlighted}"/>
</EventTrigger>
```

So if this event trigger is used on the Calendar Control how do I have to change the StoryBoard so it targets the border in my template?

Comment: Try using `{x:Reference}` like this `Storyboard.Target="{x:Reference border}"` instead of using `Storyboard.TargetName` (because this has some scope related issue).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately this gives me an "unresolved reference" error at InitializeComponent. So it seems {x:Reference} does not "dig" into the template.